# Hybrid App Development with Phonegap (CLI / Cloud Service)

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, monaca

I have used the Phonegap CLI for making my first App on Android. I have done all manually, by installing the environment (sdk), plugins, onsen ui and so on and bring them to my device. Once you are familiar with the process, I think you are really flexible.

Now I have seen that there are some cloud services like monaca and also phonegap has his own service with the builder. So my question: Are they useful for developing phonegap apps and will the make my life easier or are the just for making money. When I look at monaca it seems that the will produce a lot of tricky source code. Also I don’t know if they will work fine in association with the different plugins or the onsen ui.

So if there are some people with experience about the cloud services it would be nice to get some impressions.

Comment: This isn't a great question for StackOverflow - tools recommendations usually get removed. I believe there is another StackExchange site: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ which might be better. Also, as an aside, you might consider looking at Intel's XDK as a combination IDE and remote build environment. It is free and does make doing builds with Crosswalk for Android as well as regular Cordova builds a cinch.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would recommend Monaca, I've used it since January 2015. It has gone through a lot of changes since then, but you'll still find some weirdness/bugs. I also recommend looking at Ionic, which is similar, and also growing. Ionic is more "popular" but I still think Monaca has more to offer. They're not a gimmick trying to just make money.